# "Error: Broken Count > 0" on updates

Tags: package-management, update-manager

Here are two pictures below that clarify the situation and show the issues/errors I am seeing.

This is the error I got when the system tried to get updates:
[image: The error that I got while trying to update]

This is what I got when I tried the command mentioned in the second picture:
[image: What I got when I tried the command that they mentioned in the second pic]

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Can you help me fix the issue?

the terminal code :

```
adn7@1EK:~$ sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/25.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 100 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 222801 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvdpau1_1.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvdpau1:amd64 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg', which is different from other instances of package libvdpau1:amd64
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please post terminal output as text, not as pictures.

Comment: how can i do it please i'm new on the website ?

Comment: Copy text from the terminal and post it here as text.

Comment: @adnan.HT , `sudo mv /etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg /etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg.backup` then try `sudo apt-get install -f` again.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot @Sneetsher that was really helpful I didn't get that error after i tried the code that you gave me .
then the update is done smoothly.